# Rails: STI in Devise with different attributes for each user type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, sti

I am going start a project in Ruby on Rails, where I have three types of users

1. Single User
2. Admin User
3. Business User

Single and Admin User have attributes:

- name
- email
- password

Business users have attributes:

- business name
- address
- postal code
- email
- password

Now, what I want to achieve is how can users login with single form and signup with different attributes.(do I need separate forms for signup?)
Is STI solution better to use here or you recommend other solution? If yes to STI, than is it ok to have empty fields for user 1 and 2 in database.

I am beginner rails guy so I really don't understand what to do. A step wise solution will help me understand alot.
A tutorial may also help alot.
Looking forward to your help
Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Set up your rails application with the devise gem for authentication.

It can handle authentication for multiple user roles as specified in the documentation here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role